# Using Attribute modifiers to add armour to Elytra (MCBE)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

As the title suggests I am trying to add Elytra wings to the player, through commands, that will give them an armour bonus (in place of the missing chest plate)
I've seen plenty of examples for Vanilla Minecraft and I have tried to copy/paste, or write my own but with no luck. Here is the current command I have been working with.

```
/give @p elytra 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.Armor", Name:"generic.Armor", Amount:20,Operation:0, UUIDLeast:894654, UUIDMost:2872}]}
```

The error I get is:

> * Line 1 Column 2 Missing '}' or object member name.

I'm not entirely sure where line 1, Column 2 is. But I don't think that blindly sticking a } in the middle of my command will fix anything. I'm sure that what I'm trying to do is possible but I don't have the skill to figure out the small details myself.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see how that question and answer relates to the issue I am having. I see that they talk about tags for 'can place' and 'can destroy' but there doesn't seem to be anything about adding and changing attribute modifiers relating to damage, armour etc.

Comment: Attribute modifiers for damage and armor are a kind of NBT tag, as evidenced by the fact that the go within Curly Brackets. The linked question answers your problem by saying that it is impossible.